# Building academy on oil tile - Auto acquire oil?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

In civ 5 brave new world, if I build an academy, and then several turns later, I research oil, does the academy automatically grant me that oil if the oil is underneath it?

In one game I was playing, it appeared to be the case, because when I removed the academy to put in my oil rig, I kept the same amount of oil. But I might have been getting oil from the city-states, they were so in flux that I couldnt keep track of what I was getting from them all the time.

Comment: I believe this is the case for all Great People tiles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you'll gain the oil.

Great Person improvements count as improving strategic resources. This is so players don't have to replace them (wasting a great person) if they unknowingly put them on a strategic resource.

Comment: Yay I wasted my great person :D
Good to know for next time

Comment: Actually I said the exact opposite- you get to keep your academy and now it's on an even better tile.

Comment: No I know, I had already replaced the academy not knowing that I had gotten the oil from it

Comment: I think this applies to all resources--not just strategic ones. And you can do it even after discovering the tech that exposes the resource. However, you don't gain the same additional yields (food, production, and gold) that the regular improvement provides.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Afaik, you don't get happiness from luxury resources

Comment: @DavidHarkness You don't. This is because luxury resources are always visible so if you put an academy on your gold mine it's your own silly fault.

Answer (score 2):

Great People tiles will *always* give you strategic resources as long as you meet the prerequisites for accessing that strategic resource.

The reason for this is that strategic resources don't show up on the map until certain technologies have been unlocked.  If you pop a Great Person to make a tile improvement, and then later you realize you have to build something else there, that'd be a huge bummer.

Thus, the game counts it as having built the special tile improvement on top.